# Angular 12 update issue: Unknown error from PostCSS plugin

Tags: angular, angular11, angular12

Hi after I ran "ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12" to upgrade from 11 to 12, and then "ng serve app" I keep getting the following error:
"Unknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 8.2.14, but postcss-preset-env uses 7.0.35. Perhaps this is the source of the error below."

What's my problem? No PostCSS in package.json. I don't know about it. Thanks in advance.[image: PostCSS error]

Comment: Did you try cleaning your `node_modules` folder and re-installing the dependencies?

Comment: I am getting this same error.  I've tried a fresh yarn install several times with no luck.  Could there be a compatibility issue with a third party package?  I am not sure how to find the package causing the issue.

Comment: I submitted a github issue for this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42234

Answer (score 8):

The issue seems to be related to the file .browserslistrc, renamed from browserlist during the upgrade migration.
I resolved this issue by creating a new angular app, but only for the purposes of creating the default .browserslistrc file, and then copied that file to my upgraded app.

Answer (score 8):

Update `.browserlistrc` to this:

```
last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 11 # Angular supports IE 11 only as an opt-in. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue will occur if you have an installed version of node that is older than 12.17 as noted in this github issue. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20863

Upgrading to node.js version 12.20 or later should resolve the issue.

Note that after I did this, I also had to regenerate my yarn.lock file.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then run the following command

```
yarn install
```

OR

Try to run the following commands

```
yarn remove bootstrap
yarn add bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

Following to answer from @PAR, I did create a new project to verify the `.browserslistrc` file, the contents were the same in the updated NG12 project, except the file was under `src` folder, so I just have to move it out in the root and the project started working just fine again.